# Could we fake processor and RAM with hypervisor?

Tags: virtual-machine, emulation, vmware, virtualization, hypervisor

I hear a lot about "Hypervisors are not emulators. If you need to emulate another hardware specifications than you computer have, you need to use emulator, not hypervisor".

Well, but yesterday I saw this video on youtube - [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlH4_3ZFTTs) - which shows how to install Win 95 on modern macOS with VMware Fusion.

The strange thing for me is that on 17:39 you could see that Win 95 virtual machine is "Pentium Pro with 64 MB RAM".

[image]

Hmm! So, Fusion somehow faked processor and RAM, right? But it is not emulator, right? So, does it mean that any hypervisor can fake processor and RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of its release, Windows 95 only had code to recognize CPUIDs up to Pentium Pro.  Any processor not lower than Pentium Pro is "called" Pentium Pro.

The main difference is the Hypervisor cannot emulate CPU code. All code must run on the original processor.

The hypervisor does emulate the BIOS, which in tells the OS the hardware specs available; including RAM, Boot order and peripherals attached.

Comment: But what about memory?

Comment: *Windows 95 may fail to boot on computers with more than approximately 480 MB of memory. In such a case, reducing the file cache size or the size of video memory can help.* From [Win 95 Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_95)

Comment: @Raptor Yes, I understand, but I mean is it possible to reduce the memory with hypervisor only, without using an emulator? So, in other words, if we need to fake just the amount of memory - it could be achieved wiith hypervisor only, but to fake some advanced hardware parameters (instruction set, CPU clock rate) - we need emulator, correct?

Comment: Hypervisors control the amount of hardware(reported)/software memory available to the client os. You cannot fake more memory than you have. But, If you wish to reduce the amount of RAM, yes it is possible, that is a simple configuration parameter.  The CPU clock rate "can be reported to the os less than it is", but the operations executed will still occur as fast as the hypervisor schedules them(which can be configured through priorities). If you need to change the instruction set the only option is an emulator.

Comment: Oh, thank you, now everything much clearer. However, two additional questions. 1. What did you mean when you said that I cannot fake memory, _but_ I can reduce its amount? What's the difference? From my point of view it was the same thing. 2. Is it really possible to report lower CPU clock rate with a hypervisor? I haven't know it is possible. How it could be achieved, generally?

Comment: 1. The term fake could include more memory than the hardware has, and is not supported.   2. VMWare hypervisors have the timeTracker.apparentHz, that changes the reported frequency of the processor.  This does not cause any actual slowdown.  It is possible to throttle the CPU for a Guest OS, but unless the process is using more CPU time than the throttle it's effects will be unnoticed. As for how, the BIOS is 100% emulated by the hypervisor. It can report the hardware as it sees fit to the Guest OS.

Comment: @Strom it is actually wrong that a hypervisor or rather virtual machine monitor cannot overcommit main memory. First, there is main memory ballooning. Secondly, the physical main memory address space of your guest is virtualized so you do not have to back each page of the guest's main memory with a page frame on the host. If you assign more main memory to a guest than available on your host, your hypervisor will start swapping pages out if the guest tries to use more memory than physically available, leading to poor performance. Same concept as virtual memory in operating systems.

Comment: @b00n12 I believe you are referring to type 2 hypervisors with your "or rather virtual machine monitor" .  My answer refers generally to type 1 hypervisors, Microsoft Hyper-V and VMware ESX.   VMware ESX does allow overcommittment to share unused memory. The performance difference is reflected in the fact the OS knows and informs an application the memory has been paged **and can adjust its memory usage**, when the hypervisor swaps out memory, the processes' memory accesses slow down with no apparent cause.

Comment: @Strom Actually, even with type-1 hypervisors you should differentiate the hypervisor that is the component that provides basic resource sharing and the VMM that is the component that manages VMs and makes use of the hypervisor. Furthermore, whether or not it is a type-1 or type-2 hypervisor has nothing to do with the technique that is used to achieve virtualization. For example, back in the days VMWare ESX used dynamic binary translation even though it classifies as a type-1 hypervisor....

Answer (score 1):

When you are talking about VMWare Fusion the way this works depends on how virtualization is achieved. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Fusion) VMWare Fusion utilizes hardware-assisted virtualization, dynamic binary translation, and para-virtualization.

In the [**hardware-assited virtualization**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-Virtualisierung) case, @Strom is correct and guest instructions can be executed directly on the host CPU. Besides @Strom answer, you can fake the CPU type by trapping and emulating the *cpuid* instruction.

In the [**para-virtualization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paravirtualization) case you replace critical instructions by calls to the hypervisor which emulates the instruction on behalf of the guest. So again you emulate the *cpuid* instruction to "fake" the CPU type. Keep in mind that this requires a modified, hence para-virtualized, guest operating system.

Finally, [**dynamic binary translation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_translation) scans the guest code for critical instructions during runtime and either replaces them by traps into the hypervisor achieving some kind of "live para-virtualization" or translating blocks of guest code into equivalent blocks of host code that modifies the VM state according to the original guest code (this is e.g. how the QEMU full system emulator works). As a result, again you are able to "fake" the CPU type by emulating the *cpuid* instruction. Notice that guest and host can be the same architecture in this case, but there is no need for this.

Of course a combination of above techniques is also feasible.

As for virtualization of main memory, the hypervisor is in full control of the hardware so you can simply configure a VM with just 64MB of main memory. The VM is not able to "see" more than this due to the techniques shortly discussed above.

Please keep in mind that this just gives a very short overview of virtualization and I tried to keep it short and informative, so I know my explanations are partially not very accurate. If you are really interested in virtualization I recommend reading *"Virtual Machines: Versatile Platforms for Systems and Processes"* or the papers on the topic by *Popek & Goldberg* and *"Xen and the Art of Virtualization"*

Comment: This is an example of a type 2 "Hypervisor",  While type 2 hypervisors manage virtual machines, they can emulate the cpu instructions when needed.  "Para-Virtualization" is a form of CPU emulation.

Comment: The technique you use to achieve virtualization does not affect the rather blurry classification of type-1 and type-2 hypervisors. You are right, that today especially dynamic binary translation is used for full system simulation which typically does not classify as a hypervisor. Yet, emulation (even instruction emulation) is a common thing for a hypervisor to do, as some instructions simply trap and the hypervisor has to take action in behalf of the VM. Para-virtualization has nothing to do with CPU emulation, as it reassembles a system call interface for the guest hence the term hypercall.